# Symfony FOSUserBundle Cannot instantiate abstract class FOS\UserBundle\Model\User

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, propel

I have a fresh isntalation of Symfony 2.4 + FOSUserBundle.
I just configured FOSUserBundle, this guide: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md

Now I try to create a new user with the CLI

```
fos:user:create --super-admin user user@domain.com password1
```

And I get this error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Cannot instantiate abstract class FOS\UserBundle\Model\User in /var/www/symfony2/vendor/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle/FOS/UserBundle/Model/UserManager.php on line 55
```

**config.ylm**

```
...
fos_user:
    db_driver: propel
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: FOS\UserBundle\Model\User
...
```

**When access /register I get the same error, but /login seems to work fine (although I cant login, since I have no users)**

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance

EDITS:

new user class:

```
namespace g9\BoBundle\Model;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as MyUser;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManager;

class User extends MyUser {
    # .. no code here yet
}
```

When I use CLI to create user I get:

```
  [InvalidArgumentException]
  This user instance is not supported by the Propel UserManager implementation
```

***Should I submit another question? (The initial question got an answer***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use provided User model, you have to [extend it and create your own](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#step-3-create-your-user-class).

When you do that, set `user_class` configuration parameter to namespace of **your** User model (which extends FOSUser's one).

At the moment, your `user_class` is set to their abstract `User` and therefore it breaks.

Comment: Could you give me an example how I should I do that?
I'm very new to symfony, the only way I know of generating these classes, is by creating schema.xml and let the CLI build it.
How can i do it manually? Wich namespace should i use? what class whould i extend?

Comment: See the documentation (https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#step-3-create-your-user-class) for info on how to extend the user model.

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying and getting some erros. For example: Should I extend the BaseUser? FOS doenst provide BaseUser, only User. And I cant extend User, since I'm trying to define User. I get the feeling i'm not getting some basics here...

Comment: I've used another name for my User class, and now i get this error: "This user instance is not supported by the Propel UserManager implementation"